# Access or general query question about grouping 2 lines of data where

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

Access or general query question about grouping 2 lines of data where for example all the columns are all the same except for amount and last 1 field which is vendor id.. I have an exceptions list where if the vendor ID is in exception list don't use that use the other one then group..

Any suggestions?

e.g.
[image]

V124 is in exceptions list

Answer should be
ID1 $13 V123...

Do I use union?? or what? thanks.

I tried subquery but erros out.

```
 vid: (SELECT Table1.Vendor
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN [tl_List of Exceptions] ON Table1.Vendor = [tl_List of Exceptions].[Vendor ID]
WHERE ((([tl_List of Exceptions].[Vendor ID]) Is Null))
group by table1.[Vendor];)
```

This is my test query..

```
    SELECT Table1.[Outstanding Amount], Table1.[FMMI Obl Doc Nbr], 
(SELECT Table1.Vendor, [tl_List of Exceptions].[Vendor ID]
FROM Table1 LEFT JOIN [tl_List of Exceptions] ON Table1.Vendor = [tl_List of Exceptions].[Vendor ID]
WHERE ((([tl_List of Exceptions].[Vendor ID]) Is Null));) AS vendor
FROM Table1;
```

Trying to make this work.. any suggestions on adding the subquery? Thanks.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT A.[Outstanding Amount], A.[FMMI Obl Doc Nbr], A.vendor
FROM Table1 AS A, [tl_List of Exceptions] AS b
WHERE (((A.vendor)<>[b].[vendor ID]));
```

Lee:

```
    select v.[Doc Nbr], u.tot, first(v.[Vendor]) as vendor
from
    (
        [2_concatrelated] v inner join
        (
            select t.[Doc Nbr], sum(t.[Outstanding Amount]) as tot
            from [2_concatrelated] t
            group by t.[Doc Nbr]
        ) u on v.[Doc Nbr] = u.[Doc Nbr]
    ) left join [tl_List of Exceptions] e on v.[Vendor] = e.[Vendor id]
where   
    e.[Vendor id] is null
group by 
    v.[Doc Nbr], u.tot
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the limited information you have provided, I would suggest calculating the totals using a subquery (in which all vendors are included), and then excluding the appropriate vendors from the parent query, e.g.:

```sql
select v.col1, u.tot, first(v.col3) as vendor
from
    (
        table1 v inner join
        (
            select t.col1, sum(t.col2) as tot
            from table1 t
            group by t.col1
        ) u on v.col1 = u.col1
    ) left join [tl_List of Exceptions] e on v.col3 = e.[Vendor ID]
where   
    e.[Vendor ID] is null
group by 
    v.col1, u.tot
```

Assumed that your tables are called `Table1` and `tl_List of Exceptions` and that your fields are `Table1.col1`, `Table1.col2`, `Table1.col3`, and `tl_List of Exceptions.Vendor ID`

Comment: I've attached my test query above.. error i'm getting is:                                                    You have written a subquery that can return more than one field without using the EXISTS reserved...

Comment: Did you consider my suggestion?